# React + Laravel - Set State not defined

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Iam trying to print back the value fetched from API. The data is coming but not able to set the state

Tried everything

React.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Admin extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
         users:  []
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/api/adminUsers')
        .then(response =>{      
            this.setState({users: response.data})
            console.log(response.data)
            console.log(this.setState({users: response.data}))
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            this.setState({ errorMsg: "Something is wrong here"})
            console.log(error)
        })
}

render() {
    const{users} = this.state
    <div>

{
  users.length ?
  users.map(user => <div key= 
  {user.id}>{user.name}</div>)
  : null
}

        </div>  
     )
  }
}

export default Admin
```

The response.data showing in console is:

```
{[
created_at: "2019-08-31 14:06:29"
email: "amit.khare588@gmail.com5"
email_verified_at: null
id: 2
name: "Amit Khare"
role: "Doctor"
updated_at: "2019-08-31 14:06:29"
]}
```

I just want to print the data back

Comment: Which error occurs? On what line?

Comment: It simply says "Undefined" and is not displaying any data where the set values are supposed to come.

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: `console.log(this.setState({users: response.data}))` will always print `undefined` because `setState` doesn't actually return anything (it has no need to). And you need to show the whole of your `render` method to see why the HTML output isn't as you expect.

Comment: The `response.data` response seems weird though, the users should be objects not arrays.

Comment: Complete HTML updated in question. Thanks

Comment: there is no return statement in render method, is it a typo? Also, respose.data is strange as array is inside object without any key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems fine below is a fully working example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


class Admin extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            errorMsg: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/adminUsers')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({users: response.data.users})
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({errorMsg: "Something is wrong here"})
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    render() {
        const {users, errorMsg} = this.state;

        return <div>
            {users.length ? users.map(user => <div key={user.id}>{user.name}</div>) : null}
            {errorMsg ? <div>{errorMsg}</div> : null}
        </div>
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Admin/>, rootElement);
```

Checkout the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-fermi-ku1jr

Comment: on using this.setState({
            users: [
                {
                    created_at: "2019-08-31 14:06:29",
                    email: "test.test@gmail.com5",
                    email_verified_at: null,
                    id: 2,
                    name: "test user",
                    role: "Doctor",
                    updated_at: "2019-08-31 14:06:29"
                }
            ]
        })
Its giving result but not on using
this.setState({users: response.data})

Comment: What is the value of `response.data`? @AmitKhare

Comment: {users: Array(1)}
users: Array(1)
0: {id: 2, name: "Amit Khare", email: "amit.khare588@gmail.com5", email_verified_at: null, role: "Doctor", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Comment: I updated the answer, you need to use `response.data.users` instead of `response.data` @AmitKhare

Comment: Worked beautifully. 
Thanks a lot.
Can you offer some explanation please

Comment: Your API endpoint(`/api/adminUsers`) returns an object(`{users: []}`). The object has one key called `users`. That key contains an array of all the users. By assigning the array(`response.data.users`) to `users` key in state you can loop through all the users and display their details in the `render` method. @AmitKhare

Comment: Thanks again. Saved the day for me

Comment: Glad to hear! Could you mark the answer as solution/upvote it so other people can find this solution? @AmitKhare

Comment: Did That. Sorry got confused, where to click and all that.